# Query string http param in play framework 1.2.5

Tags: playframework-1.x

i need to add a route for following syntax

```
/bidding/12345?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

in my routes file i add like this

```
GET /bidding/{id}          Application.bidding
```

i try to send request with query param `/bidding/12345?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN` like above but play response is 404 (not found), i was using play framework 1.2.5

thanks for any response to my question, and sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL you are trying to access is not represented correctly in the routes file.

If you would like to access the URL:

```
/bidding/12345?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

The routes file entry will need to be changed to the following:

```
GET /bidding          Application.bidding
```

Play will use its magic to route that GET request to the following method in the Application controller:

```
public static void bidding(String access_token)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your route configuration seems ok : are you sure you have a valid public static method bidding in your Application class ? Could you post the source of this method ?